# I am using snowflake and receiving the following error: error line 0 at position -1 from below query

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using the below CTE in snowflake and the below query. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

```
    with 
    ll as (
       select 
         count(*) as count
       from a.view
       where s_type = 'LL'
    ),
    acc as (
       select 
          sum(num_acc) as total
       from b.view
    ),
    prod as (
       select
          prod_version as prod
       from c.view
    )
    select
      prod.prod as product_type,
      ll.count as ll_count,
      acc.total as total_num_acc,
      ll_count / total_num_acc as ch
    from ll
    join acc, prod
    group by product_type;
```

This results in this error after running the query:
error line 0 at position -1

Comment: I removed the single backticks at the start and end of the query under the assumption that those weren't meant to be visible in the question. If those were in your actual query, then feel free to add back (also that would cause this error).

Comment: This `from ll join acc, prod` makes no sense. If you specify a `join`, which in this case is in implicit `INNER JOIN` you need to specify an `ON` clause. If you can share sample data and desired results we can help craft the SQL to get there. I can't figure out what you are trying to do with your non-working SQL, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your query and the full error is:

```
[42601][1104] SQL compilation error: error line 0 at position -1 
'SYS_VW.COUNT_0' in select clause is neither an aggregate nor in the group by clause.
```

Indeed in the final query some columns are directly used but they are not in the `group by` clause (and not aggregated).

According to your needs, one solution would be to complete the last line as:

```sql
group by product_type, ll_count, total_num_acc;
```

Other solutions would consist of removing the `group by` clause, or use aggregate functions (like `sum`, `count`, etc.) on the `ll_count` and `total_num_acc` columns.